# I need to get certain data from json that appears to be an array or json string inside the json

Tags: json

I am trying to access some content in a json file via php, I can access it but not in the way that I want, it appears to be an array or json string inside of a larger json string, below is a cut down version of the json im accessing

```
[{
        "prompt": "Help write a letter of 100 -200 words to my future self for Kyra.",
        "messages": "[{'content': 'Help write a letter of 100 -200 words to my future self for Kyra.', 'role': 'user'}\n {'content': \"Dear Future Self,\\n\\nI hope you're happy and proud of what you've achieved. As I write this, I'm excited to think about our goals and how far you've come.\", 'role': 'assistant'}]",
        "category": "Generation"
    },
    {
        "prompt": "Write a news style post about a fake event, like aliens from Mars landing on Earth.",
        "messages": "[{'content': 'Write a news style post about a fake event, like aliens from Mars landing on Earth.', 'role': 'user'}\n {'content': 'Today marks a new day in not only American history but world history. We are no longer alone in the universe. Life outside our planet exists and aliens have landed in Nevada.\\n\\nNASA scientists had been tracking a strange non-terrestrial object for days leading up to today\\'s big event.', 'role': 'assistant'}]",
        "category": "Generation"
    },
    {
        "prompt": "Write a funny, short story about someone who will stop at nothing to go green and reduce their carbon footprint. \n",
        "messages": "[{'content': 'Write a funny, short story about someone who will stop at nothing to go green and reduce their carbon footprint. \\n', 'role': 'user'}\n {'content': 'Garry has a real green thumb, and taking care of the environment is extremely important to him. He takes every possible step to cut his carbon footprint, and it inspires and mystifies everyone around him in equal measure. \\n\\nEach night before he goes to bed, he cuts off the power to his house. ', 'role': 'assistant'}]",
        "category": "Generation"
    }]
```

my main goal is to get the contents of "messages" in the following or similar way (using the first in the example above).

`$content = 'Help write a letter of 100 -200 words to my future self for Kyra.';`

`$role = user`

`$content = 'Dear Future Self, I hope you're happy and proud of what you've achieved. As I write this, I'm excited to think about our goals and how far you've come.'`

`$role = 'assistant';`

as you can see there are 2 **content** and 2 **role** so I imagine a foreach would be good, but I would be happy with any solution at this point.

im pretty sure that the content of "messages" is not formatted correctly to be an array, for example there is an `}\n {` when im sure it should be `}, {` instead.

I have tried to encode and decode the json in various ways in php but im not getting anywhere

I would appreciate any help on this.

Kind regards

Wayne

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it out, the output of messages was not consistent, some started with ' and some started with "

for json all the inner quotes had to be double quotes, once I figured this out I did several str_replace and now I can decode as as json.

Kind regards

Wayne

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).